# Mod Rewrite and GET Request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to clean up my URLs using mod_rewrite in my .htaccess file.  Is it possible to rewrite an outgoing GET request?

```
http://local.thisapp.com/earnings?tab=total&title=74bcfbdce5ba4fe585e0
```

to

```
http://local.this.com/earnings/total/74bcfbdce5ba4fe585e0
```

It seems to be going the opposite direction.  Here is a sample rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?earnings/(total|monthly|episode|sales)/([a-z0-9]{20}|0)/?$ /earnings.php?tab=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "outgoing GET request"? Do you mean that a link on the page you're serving needs to be rewritten or that your webserver is actually making outgoing requests?

Comment: I send a GET request from the /earnings page (it directs to the same page)...by default the GET request gets added as a query string.   I don't want to see the query string when I send the GET request, I want to see the re-written URL

Comment: You did not understand the question @JonLin asked. The question is: is that GET request a request your _server_ sends to some other server, so some sort of background request? Or does "outgoing" here mean the links (references) you yourself send out to your clients which they then can follow?

Comment: Don't you understand?  It's a web page, that has a form with 'get' method, and action='.   It calls itself, but the new url has a query string because it is a get request.   I don't want to see the new querystring...see what's wrong?

Comment: It's a web page on my server.  It calls itself with a get query to show data matching the get parameters

Comment: Sure, I know how webservers and urls work, I was asking specifically what you meant by an "outgoing" GET request. Since you're talking about "rewriting" a request, which only happens on the server's side, I wanted clarification whether you meant that your server was sending outgoing requests. The rewrite engine can only rewrite incoming requests, so links on your webpage can't be rewritten as they are being served. You'd need to change the links on your web page, or issue a *redirect* so the browser loads a new URL

Comment: It is an internal request, and it looks like the answer to my question is no. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since this appears to be a problem with what URL is being displayed in a browser's location you can either edit your webpage so the URL looks the way you want it to or you can do a redirect to tell the browser to load an entirely different URL. This can sometimes have some adverse effects since you're adding additional path segments to your URL and that will literally break all of your relative links, including any scripts or CSS that may be linked using a relative link.

The concept with a redirect/rewrite is that all of the rewriting happens on the server's end, while a redirect happens on the browser's end.

In this particular case, you want to redirect the browser to load a new URL if it sees the URL with the query string, and internally rewrite it *back* to the request with a query string.

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect the browser if an incoming request has the query string
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /earnings\?tab=([^&]+)&title=([^&\ ])
RewriteRule ^ /earnings/%1/%2/ [L,R]

# internally rewrite the request back to the query string
RewriteRule ^/?earnings/(total|monthly|episode|sales)/([a-z0-9]{20}|0)/?$ /earnings.php?tab=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```